# Opration in Nested Array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an nested array like as follows

```
var x=[1,2,[3,4,[5,6,[7,8,[9,10]]]]]
```

I want to perform some operation in array suppose **multiplication** of each elements with **2** then the result will be as follows

```
[2,4,[6,8,[10,12,[14,16,[18,20]]]]]
```

So far I have done as follows

```
function nestedArrayOperation(arr){
    var p=[];
    arr.forEach(function(item,index){
        if(Array.isArray(item)){
            p.push(nestedArrayOperation(item))
            return
        }
        p.push(item*2);//multiply by 2
        return 
    });
    return p;
}
```

```js
function nestedArrayOperation(arr){
 var p=[];
 arr.forEach(function(item,index){
  if(Array.isArray(item)){
   p.push(nestedArrayOperation(item))
   return
  }
  p.push(item*2);//Multiply by 2
  return 
 });
 return p;
}

var x=[1,2,[3,4,[5,6,[7,8,[9,10]]]]]
console.log(nestedArrayOperation(x))
```

```css
.as-console-row-code{white-space: nowrap!important;}
```

Here I am performing operation inside the function that is hard coded, I want to make **Generic nestedArrayOperation** where operation will be decided by user like **map, reduce** etc. function works.

Like in `map` function we can do any operation
    [1,2,3,4].map(x=>x**2)//it will return [1,4,9,16]
    or
    [1,2,3,4].map(x=>x*2)//it will return [2,4,6,8]

Example like as follows:

```
arr.nestedArrayOperation(x=>x*2)
//or
arr.nestedArrayOperation(x=>x+5)
```

Please help to create that generic

Thank You

Comment: you mean [`Array.prototype.Yourfunction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) ?

Comment: That I know but how it will be like map and reduce function

Comment: @SourabhSomani *like map and reduce function* Can you be more specific?

Comment: I can add in array function using `array.prototype` but I want to make that generic means `x+5` or `x+3` or any operation I can

Comment: @SourabhSomani and do you expect the recursion part to be handled by this function?

Comment: Notice that you should have used `map`, not `forEach` + `push`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for

```js
function nestedArrayOperation(arr, callback) {
 return arr.map(function(item,index) {
  if (Array.isArray(item))
   return nestedArrayOperation(item, callback);
        else
            return callback(item, index);
    });
}
var example = [1,2,[3,4,[5,6,[7,8,[9,10]]]]];
console.log(nestedArrayOperation(example, x=>x*2));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take a callback which checks the value and map the array or the multiplicated value.

This proposal uses [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and returns a new array.

```js
var times2 = v => Array.isArray(v) ? v.map(times2) : 2 * v,
    x = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6, [7, 8, [9, 10]]]]],
    x2 = x.map(times2);

console.log(x2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Pass the callback function as parameter of prototype function.
2. Then pass also with recursive function call
3. For more simple form use `ternary operator` within `Array#map`

```js
Array.prototype.nestedArrayOperation = function(callback) {
  return this.map((item, index) => Array.isArray(item) ? item.nestedArrayOperation(callback): callback(item));
}

var x = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6, [7, 8, [9, 10]]]]]

console.log(x.nestedArrayOperation((x) => x + 2))
console.log(x.nestedArrayOperation((x) => x * 2))
```

```css
.as-console-row-code {
  white-space: nowrap!important;
}
```